# Strange manner in multiplying a double value by 100000 in Qt (c++)

Tags: c++, qt, double

Can anybody explain this:

```
double nnn = 2678.87;
QVariant vvv(2678.87);
qDebug() << qRound(nnn*1000.0);    //--> 2678870
qDebug() << qRound(nnn*10000.0);   //--> 26788700
qDebug() << qRound(nnn*100000.0);  //--> 267887000
qDebug() << qRound(nnn*1000000.0); //--> 2147483647 !
qDebug() << qRound(vvv.toDouble()*1000000.0);  //--> -2147483648 !!!
```

The two last statements also have strange result in following format:

```
qDebug() << qRound(nnn*1000000); //--> 2147483647 !
qDebug() << qRound(vvv.toDouble()*1000000);  //--> -2147483648 !!!
```

I need to use last statement but it is wrong apparently!

Comment: Oops, didn't notice the negative sign on that last example.  Might not be a duplicate after all.

Comment: But this is not a duplicate question!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: The desired value can't be represented as an `int`.  Try [`qRound64`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#qRound64) instead.

Comment: `qRound` returns an `int`, your value is larger than an `int`, try [`qround64`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#qRound64) instead (though you'll still eventually run into precision problems)

Comment: `qRound()` returns an `int`.   It appears that, on your system, an `int` is 32 bits, and `nnn*1000000.0` produces a value that exceeds what a 32-bit `int` can represent.  Either `qRound()` is deliberately catching the overflow and producing the maximum value an `int` can represent on your platform, or is falling back to what is allowed by C++ standards (IIRC, that is undefined behaviour, but I haven't checked if that has changed to unspecified or other behaviours in later standards).

Comment: OK. That's true. Please someone add this issue as an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`qRound` returns an `int`, your value is larger than will fit in an `int` without overflowing. try [`qround64`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtglobal.html#qRound64) instead.

Note you'll still eventually run into precision problems, a `double` can only exactly represent integers up to around 9 * 10<sup>15</sup>.